# Unable to communicate with ardrone using ardrone_automation

Tags: ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Im trying to unravel the problem I have with communicating with the ardrone using  ardrone_automation.

I have the ardone connected via wifi and it is visable, no ethernet connected. I have had the ardone running on this computer previously using another application (closed long ago). Drone is on and connected via wifi.

When I try to communicate I get:

nigel@nigel-Satellite-P100:~$ rosnode list

ERROR: Unable to communicate with master!

I have installed all the program as per your instructions and when I go to run it I get the following problem:

nigel@nigel-Satellite-P100:~$ rosrun ardrone_autonomy ardrone_driver

Wait authentification

Wait authentification

Wait authentification

===================+> 192.168.1.1

[ERROR] [1375096491.668394796]: [registerPublisher] Failed to contact master at [localhost:11311].  Retrying...

This is my hosts file:
127.0.0.1    localhost

127.0.1.1    nigel-Satellite-P100

The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback

fe00::0 ip6-localnet

ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix

ff02::1 ip6-allnodes

ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

I think I made it worse using:

$ export ROS_HOSTNAME=localhost

$ export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://'localhost:11311' ('added so as not to post link')

Please help !

Answer:

I found the problem was I did not have a launch file which included roscore

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69577/unable-to-communicate-with-ardrone-using-ardrone_automation/) by [Nigel](https://answers.ros.org/users/5623/nigel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-07-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nevik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5620/nevik/) on 2013-08-01**:
Please post your resolution as an Answer (using the form on the bottom), so this Question is marked as answered :)

**Comment by [Nigel](https://answers.ros.org/users/5623/nigel/) on 2013-08-04**:
Does this mean I get Karma points now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the problem was I did not have a launch file which included roscore

---

Originally posted by [Nigel](https://answers.ros.org/users/5623/nigel/) with karma: 16 on 2013-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0